# SED: How to delete from the second match to the end of the file

Tags: linux, sed

I have the following file

```
Name            ITEM  Description
fa1(RM01):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3

fa2(RM02):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3
```

I need to remove from the second match "(RM0", including that line and everything below.
I need to delete this way because there are several files where "fa1 (RM01)" and "fa2 (RM02)" change places.

And I can't delete by number of lines either because the number of items can change.

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but it sounds like you want `awk '/RM0/ && a++{exit}1' input-file`

Answer (score 2):

If you have text in blocks separated by a blank line delimiter, you use this simple awk to print the first block:

```
$ awk -v RS= 'FNR==1' file
Name            ITEM  Description
fa1(RM01):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3
```

To take your post *literally* you want to print the first block with `RM0` in it. Same method:

```
$ awk -v RS= '/RM0/ && cnt++<1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/RM0/{x;/./Q;x;h}' file
```

On a match of `RM0` set a flag in the hold space. On a subsequent match quit processing.

N.B. The hold space is empty at start of processing and the `Q` quits without printing the current line.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to remove from the second match "(RM0", including that line and everything below

You can do this:

```
sed ':a; /(RM0/! { n; b a; }; :b; n; /(RM0/ Q; b b' < input
```

Explanation:

- `:a` - label 'a'
- `/(RM0/! { n; b a; }` - for a line that does not match the (basic) regular expression `(RM0`, perform the following group of commands

  - `n` - (print the current line and) read the next line
  - `b a` - branch to label 'a'
- `:b` - label 'b'
- `n` - (print the current line and) read the next line
- `/(RM0/ Q` - if the current line matches the (basic) regular expression `(RM0` then stop processing input and exit without printing the current line
- `b b` - branch to label 'b'

That's a bit unusual for a sed script in that it processes the whole input in a single sed cycle.  It reads and output lines until it sees the first instance of the pattern, then it outputs and reads lines until it reaches the second instance of the pattern, at which point it terminates.

The `Q` is specific to GNU `sed`.  If you don't want to depend on that then you can use this variation:

```
sed -n ':a; /(RM0/! { p; n; b a; }; :b; p; n; /(RM0/ q; b b' < input
```

That's functionally almost the same, but the `-n` option suppresses auto-printing the current line when the `q` command is executed.  That also turns off auto-printing by the `n` command, and that is compensated by adding an explicit `p` (print) command before each `n`.

Comment: This removes every other match for RMO except the first occurance.

Comment: Well yes, @HatLess, that's what the question asks for: "I need to remove from the second match '(RM0', including ***that line and everything below***."

Comment: Or refer to the title: "delete from the second match to the end of the file".

Comment: Indeed. Please ignore my comment. I failed to read to title and it would seem the question too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the file itself, this is easy with `ed`:

```sh
printf "%s\n" '/(RM0/;//,$ d' w | ed -s file.txt
```

This first sets the current line to the first one matching the regular expression `(RM0`, then **d**eletes everything from the *next* line that matches the same RE to the end of the file, and **w**rites the modified file back to disk.

To print out the first part of the file instead of editing it, if this is just part of a longer pipeline:

```sh
printf "%s\n" '/(RM0/;//,$ d' ',p' Q | ed -s file.txt
```

or

```sh
printf "%s\n" "/(RM0/;1,//-2 p" | ed -s input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was your input:

```
$ cat file
Name            ITEM  Description
fa1(RM01):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3

fa2(RM02):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3

fa3(RM03):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3
```

From `I need to remove from the second match "(RM0", including that line and everything below.` it sounds like you want one or the other of these, but it's not clear which from your question:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!(/\(RM0/ && (++c == 2))' file
Name            ITEM  Description
fa1(RM01):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3

fa3(RM03):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3
```

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!(/\(RM0/ && (++c >= 2))' file
Name            ITEM  Description
fa1(RM01):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3
```

but it's also possible that all you really need is one or the other of these:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR!=2' file
Name            ITEM  Description
fa1(RM01):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3

fa3(RM03):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3
```

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==1' file
Name            ITEM  Description
fa1(RM01):      1     word1
                2     word2
                3     word3
```

Or something else. Lots of possibilities...

Comment: Although the wording in the question body is ambiguous by itself, I think the question title makes the intended interpretation clear: "delete from the second match to the end of the file".

Comment: @JohnBollinger yeah but the sample input only has 2 records in it so deleting the 2nd record of that file IS deleting to the end of the file. We just don't know what the OP wants to do if there's a 3rd record. We also don't really know if testing for RM0 is necessary or if the OP really just wants to delete the 2nd record (or from the 2nd record). Thinking about that more, I probably shouldn't have bothered answering...